# Finding an angle expression in terms of argument and complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Suppose I have an arbitrary triangle, $ADC$, oriented in a clockwise fashion. Using complex numbers $a$, $d$ and $c$, we represent the vertices $A$, $D$ and $C$ respectively.

My question is: If I would like to find the angle $ADC$ in terms of  $\arg(.)$ and $a$, $d$ and $c$, how can I write them?

My guess is: $\angle ADC=\arg(d-c)-\arg (d-a)=\arg \bigg(\dfrac{d-c}{d-a} \bigg)$.
If I am wrong, what should it be then? Also, can someone kindly help me to understand the problem geometrically? My apologies if the question is trivial but I am having a really hard time trying to visualise how to set up the problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is right, we are using the basic properties of complex numbers. Just recall to assume $\arg$ defined in a proper interval as $[0,2\pi)$.

In order to visualize better let consider $D$ as the origin then we obtain

$$\angle ADC=\arg(c’)-\arg(a’)=\arg(c’/a’)=\arg \bigg(\dfrac{c-d}{a-d} \bigg)$$

Comment: Hi @gimusi, by setting $D$ as the origin as you mentioned, the problem became a whole lot easier to see! Thank you!

Comment: Yes indeed! Well done, you are welcome, Bye.